# Caldroidlistener doesn't work under Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, caldroid

I'm trying to implement Caldroid in my Software. To check if the user is clicking anything, I am setting up a Listener like this:

```
val listener = object : CaldroidListener() {
        fun onSelectDate(date: Date, view: View) {
            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext, formatter.format(date),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }

        override fun onChangeMonth(month: Int, year: Int) {
            val text = "month: $month year: $year"
            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext, text,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }

        fun onLongClickDate(date: Date, view: View) {
            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext,
                "Long click " + formatter.format(date),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }

        override fun onCaldroidViewCreated() {
            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext,
                "Caldroid view is created",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }

}
```

However:Android puts out an error on the "object"-tag, saying: "Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun onSelectDate(date: Date!, view: View!): Unit defined in com.roomorama.caldroid.Caldroidlistener'

Does anyone know how to deal with this?

Comment: Have you tried replacing this bit: `onSelectDate(date: Date, view: View) ` with this one  `onSelectDate(date: Date?, view: View?) ` ?

Comment: I did, unfortunately it stays the same

Comment: And if you remove the object: ? Does it show that error again or a new one ?

Comment: It marks the whole part and says "cannot create an instance of an abstract class"
if i remove the "object:"